# Reading a binary file in c++ with stringstream

Tags: c++, stringstream

I want to write/read data from a file. Is it possible to divide the file (inside the code) in multiple Strings/Sections? Or read data untill a specific line?

Just like: "Read the Data untill line 32, put it inside a String, read the next 32 lines and put it into another string"

Im already know how to read and find data with seekp but i dont really like it because my code always gets to long.

I already found some code but i dont understand it how it works:

```
dataset_t* DDS::readFile(std::string filename)
{
dataset_t* dataset = NULL;

std::stringstream ss;
std::ifstream fs;
uint8_t tmp_c;

try
{
    fs.open(filename.c_str(), std::ifstream::in);

    if (!fs)
    {
        std::cout << "File not found: " << filename << std::endl;
        return NULL;
    }

    while(fs.good())
    {
        fs.read((char*)&tmp_c, 1);
        if (fs.good()) ss.write((char*)&tmp_c, 1);
    }
    fs.close();

    dataset = new dataset_t();

    const uint32_t bufferSize = 32;
    char* buffer = new char[bufferSize];

    uint32_t count = 1;
    while(ss.good())
    {
        ss.getline(buffer, bufferSize);

        dataitem_t dataitem;
        dataitem.identifier = buffer;
        dataitem.count = count;
        dataset->push_back(dataitem);

        count++;
    }

    return dataset;
}
catch(std::exception e)
{
    cdelete(dataset);
    return NULL;
}

}
```

The Code edits a binary save file.

Or can someone link me a website where i can learn more about buffers and stringstreams?

Comment: You don't have a `std::ios_base::binary` flag. But yes, all files are binary...

Comment: I'm a bit confused, you talk about binary files *and* "lines" as in "lines of text". What is the actual contents of the file? If it's text, why do you want to read it as a binary files? Please elaborate on the contents of the file and what you want to do with it.

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html would be a great place to start - most of what you'll ever want to do has probably already been done.

Comment: If you do actually mean just a text file, you could use std::getline in a loop counting the lines. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline

Comment: I can  really explain the file. Its decrypted. I contains some settings and i want to read them. And my problem now is: I need something to read that data. Thx for the links, they are perfect for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create some classes to model your requirement: a `take<N>` for 'grab 32 lines', and a `lines_from` to iterate over lines.

Your `lines_from` class would take any `std::istream`: something encoded, something zipped, ... as long as it gives you a series of characters.  The `take<N>` would convert that into `array<string, N>` chunks.

Here's a snippet that illustrates it:

```
int main(){
    auto lines = lines_from{std::cin};

    while(lines.good()){
        auto chunk = take<3>(lines);
        std::cout << chunk[0][0] << chunk[1][0] << chunk[2][0] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

And here are the supporting classes and functions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

class lines_from {
public:
    std::istream &in;
    using value_type = std::string;

    std::string operator*() {
        std::string line;
        std::getline(in, line);
        return line;
    }

    bool good() const {
        return in.good();
    }
};

template<int N, class T>
auto take(T &range){
    std::array<typename T::value_type, N> value;
    for (auto &e: value) { e = *range; }
    return value;
}
```

(demo on [cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh/7piba))

Comment: Thanks that was what i was looking for :). But i have to make some changes

Comment: You are welcome.  you could prove that by pressing the accept button :)